# Trying to sort a file using Insertion Sort c#

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I am trying to sort a file in c#, the file has strings ( different days of the week in a list without). The sorting works on a normal array got a example

```
string[] array = { "Monday", "Thursday", "Monday", "Wednesday", "Friday", "Tuesday", "Friday", "Tuesday", "Thursday", "Wednesday" };
```

when put through the sorting algorithm - outputs the days in order: Monday Monday Friday Friday Thursday Thursday Tuesday Tuesday Wednesday Wednesday. But when I change the array to the file array (shown in the code below) it is not sorted. I'm quite new to c# programming. I am trying to make the file output like the one above.

There is pieces in the code that I have kept, for my own testing purposes so i'm sorry for the confusion. What happens is:

Some code that is not shown is just: the user enters a value between 1-10 this is known as userFileInput.

I would must appreciate any help. Thanks!

CODE:

```
string[] value = MethodA();
            //Console.WriteLine(value[1]);

            string[] array = { value[userFileInput - 1] }; //userFileInput is the users choice of file
            //string[] array = { "Monday", "Thursday", "Monday", "Wednesday", "Friday", "Tuesday", "Friday", "Tuesday", "Thursday", "Wednesday" };
            InsertSort(array);
            for (int x = 0; x < array.Length; x++)
                Console.WriteLine(array[x]);

           Console.WriteLine("Original File --------------------------------------------------\n");
           Console.WriteLine(value[userFileInput - 1]);

           Console.ReadKey();
        }





        static string[] MethodA() //FILE METHOD - READS IN THE FILES THEN RETURNS THEM TO MAIN METHOD
        {
            StreamReader dayFile = new StreamReader("c:..\\Files\\Day.txt"); StreamReader dateFile = new StreamReader("c:..\\Files\\Date.txt");
            StreamReader sh1Open = new StreamReader("c:..\\Files\\SH1_Open.txt"); StreamReader sh1Close = new StreamReader("c:..\\Files\\SH1_Close.txt");
            StreamReader sh1Volume = new StreamReader("c:..\\Files\\SH1_Volume.txt"); StreamReader sh1Diff = new StreamReader("c:..\\Files\\SH1_Diff.txt");
            StreamReader sh2Open = new StreamReader("c:..\\Files\\SH2_Open.txt"); StreamReader sh2Close = new StreamReader("c:..\\Files\\SH2_Close.txt");
            StreamReader sh2Volume = new StreamReader("c:..\\Files\\SH2_Volume.txt"); StreamReader sh2Diff = new StreamReader("c:..\\Files\\SH2_Diff.txt");

            string dayString = dayFile.ReadToEnd(); string dateString = dateFile.ReadToEnd(); string Sh1OpenString = sh1Open.ReadToEnd(); string Sh1CloseString = sh1Close.ReadToEnd();
            string Sh1VolumeString = sh1Volume.ReadToEnd(); string Sh1DiffString = sh1Diff.ReadToEnd(); string Sh2OpenString = sh2Open.ReadToEnd(); string Sh2CloseString = sh2Close.ReadToEnd();
            string Sh2VolumeString = sh2Volume.ReadToEnd(); string Sh2DiffString = sh2Diff.ReadToEnd();

            string[] fileArray = new string[] { Sh1OpenString, Sh1CloseString, Sh1VolumeString, Sh1DiffString , dateString ,  Sh2OpenString, Sh2CloseString, Sh2VolumeString, Sh2DiffString ,dayString };
            return fileArray;
        }

        static void InsertSort(IComparable[] array)
        {
              int i, j;

            for (i = 1; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                IComparable value = array[i];
                j = i - 1;
                while ((j >= 0) && (array[j].CompareTo(value) > 0))
                {
                    array[j + 1] = array[j];
                    j = j - 1;
                }
                array[j + 1] = value;

            } 

        }
```

Comment: What are files containing?

Comment: Some of them contain a list of days, some dates, some numbers like 75.350
74.430

Comment: If your files contains duplicate days or days of week, you shouldn't expect the sorting algorithm to 'delete' those duplicate entries. Sorting and grouping are two way different processes.

Comment: The array you want to sort contains the content of each of the files. If you want to get the lines in file, use `shXVolumn.ReadAllLines()` which returns array of strings and then merge all these arrays into one.

Comment: I thought the file would be read in, then the sorting algorithm should sort/group them?

Comment: Do you want to sort the lines from all those files or sort the content of the files? I.e. if file 1 has lines A, D and file 2 has D, F and file 3 has B, J - do you want the result to be A, B, D, D, F, J or {A, D}, {B, J}, {D, F}?

Comment: I just want to sort a selected file at the moment, this being day.txt which includes a list of different day names. I'm trying to bunch all of the days together in alphabetical order - so all the fridays will be bunched together, all the mondays etc

Answer (score 0):

I think the problems is that in array you keep somethink like this

```
string array = new[] { "Monday Saturday Monday", "Wednesday Thursday Monday" , ... };
```

And it should look something like this

```
string array = new[] { "Monday", "Saturday", "Monday", "Wednesday", "Thursday" , "Monday" , ... };
```

To make that kind of array you can iterate through all the lines from file an add it to a list.

```
public List<string> ReadAllLines(StreamReader sr)
{
    List<string> allLines = new List<string>();
    string line; 
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) 
    {
        allLines.Add(line);
    }
    return allLines;
}
```

Instead of this type of line of code

```
string dayString = dayFile.ReadToEnd();
```

You use this line with the method we created, which will return separated lines from file.

```
List<string> dayString = ReadAllLines(dayFile);
// to the same with the rest of the files
```

After you read all lines from files you append it to `fileArray`. When the array is done you can return it. We have to change  `MethodA` return type in `string[][]`.

```
 List<string[]> fileArray = new List<string>();
 fileArray.Add(fileArray.ToArray());
 // add from other files too
 return fileArray.ToArray();
```

You use this like this

```
// rest of the code
string[][] value = MethodA(); // notice string[][]
string[] array = value[userFileInput - 1]; //userFileInput is the users choice of file
InsertSort(array);
//rest of the code
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm not certain if i'v copied/written everything in right though. Should I change the 'string[] array = { value[userFileinput - 1] };' to something else?